# .load and .unload external page inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jQuery function to load an external page inside a div on click.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".more", function() {
$("#wait").load("www.google.com")
}),
$(document).on("click",".more",function(){
$("#wait").empty()
})
```

```css
#wait{
  width:80vw;
  height:80vh;
  position:fixed;
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  background:red;
 }

#more{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="more">CLICK</div>
<div id="wait"></div>
```

It works but if I click to show that div again it will be empty.
What the alternative to `.empty()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Need to show us more html context since we have no way to know why `.more` and `.less` are the same thing. Sounds like you want `show()` and `hide()` or simply `toggle()`. Can find all these in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: @charlietfl You should consider .more and .less as a button, the same one it just changes name once clicked.

I want it to load and toggle, but when toggled I want that page to disappear from the div.

Comment: but to be honest it is incumbent on you to show us how that works as per [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your post it seems you want to load it once and then just toggle.

```
$(document).on("click", ".more", function() {
  var $wait = $("#wait");
  if ($wait.html().length==0) $wait.load("about.html");
  $wait.show();
  $(this).toggleClass("more less");
});
$(document).on("click",".less",function(){
  $("#wait").hide();
  $(this).toggleClass("less more");
});
```

To add and delete each time you click the SAME button try this which seems to be very much what you already tried

```
$(document).on("click", ".more", function() {
  $("#wait").load("about.html");
  $(this).toggleClass("more less");
});
$(document).on("click",".less",function(){
  $("#wait").empty();
  $(this).toggleClass("less more");
});
```

One event handler:

```
$(document).on("click", ".moreorless", function() {
  if ($(this)hasClass("more")) {
    $("#wait").load("about.html");
    $(this).toggleClass("more less");
  }
  else {
    $("#wait").empty();
    $(this).toggleClass("less more");
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to load it and then toggle exactly but when it's toggled I want it to disappear from the page. I tried your code and it seems not working @mplungjan

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Errors in the console?

Comment: No errors but the hide() function does not delete the content from the div.

Comment: I added a toggleClass to reuse the same button. The hide does not delete the content, just hides it. You did not like empty so...

Comment: if they are same button only need one event listener

Answer (score 1):

Why not just load the data on page load and then [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the display when button is clicked?

```
$(function(){
    // add the content right when page loads
    $("#wait").load("about.html");
    $('#more').click(function(){
        // toggle display
        $("#wait").toggle();
        // toggle class
        $(this).toggleClass("less more");
    });
});
```

Comment: I asked the same and posted almost the same. He wants the click to load and later to remove the content

Comment: I don't know I felt that witouth that content the page is much more lighter but indeed once loaded it can stay there. upvote

Comment: no need to worry about being *"light"* when it is loaded by ajax. Won't affect overall initial page load speed since the ajax would be done after page load